# Attempt to Nesting a React JSS class in another JSS class?

Tags: nested, jss

I have the following situation I create two classes react JSS classes
this classes are nested one inside the other.

for further understanding I will explain the whole situation,
think of a menu-sidebar, this menu-sidebar has its list elements.
each list element has an icon and a text.

Father class would be the **classes.list-item**
childrens would be **classes.icon** and **classes.text**

I tried as you can see what the documentation says with the quotation, but I think the quotes don't detect the JSS class, also tried using "." or not using it before the class.

```
export default menuItems => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex'
  },
  listItems: {
    '&:focus': {
      background: '#549be6'
    },
    '&:hover': {
      background: 'red',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    '& .icon': {
      color: '#549be6'
    }
    '& text':{
      color: '#549be6'
    }
  }
});

//CSS wise what I attempt to do is the following

.listItems:hover .icon{
  color:red;
}

.listItems:hover .text{
  color:red;
}
```

Now with JSS am trying to do the following I want when hovering the father component that both children components change color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
listItems: {
    ...
    '&:hover': {
      background: 'red',
      fontWeight: 'bold',

      '& .icon': {
        color: 'red'
      }
      '& .text':{
        color: 'red'
      } 
    },
    '& .icon': {
      color: '#549be6'
    }
    '& .text':{
      color: '#549be6'
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-jss-playground-od57m?fontsize=14) with another example.

Comment: Its the same I had but without the focus, that I need too.

listItems: {
    '&:hover': {
      background: 'red',
      fontWeight: 'bold'

      '& $icon': {
        color: 'red'
      }
      '& $text':{
        color: 'red'
      } 
    },
  }

also shouldn't it be like this considering they are JSS classes?